# how do I get rpart to work with increased number of factors?

Tags: r, lapply, decision-tree, sapply, rpart

I observe that just for the rpart package (for decision tree models), as I increase the number of factor levels in my data, the package slows down drastically. I have compared with other packages, and only for rpart, this seems to be the case. Below is a graph of trying out various algorithms on my data. The X-axis shows the number of factor levels used and the Y-axis shows the time in seconds. As you can see, for rpart, the spike for increasing number of factors is huge. [image]

By reading a few sources online, and a page from stack overflow, I understand that this has to do with the for loop in rpart:::rpart.matrix and changing it with [ls]apply will speed up that part of the code.

This is the original code

```
function (frame)
{
    if (!inherits(frame, "data.frame") || is.null(attr(frame,
        "terms")))
        return(as.matrix(frame))
    for (i in 1:ncol(frame)) {
        if (is.character(frame[[i]]))
            frame[[i]] <- as.numeric(factor(frame[[i]]))
        else if (!is.numeric(frame[[i]]))
            frame[[i]] <- as.numeric(frame[[i]])
    }
    X <- model.matrix(attr(frame, "terms"), frame)[, -1L, drop = FALSE]
    colnames(X) <- sub("^`(.*)`", "\\1", colnames(X))
    class(X) <- c("rpart.matrix", class(X))
    X
}
```

This is the change suggested to speed up the loop

```
# exactly the same as rpart.matrix, but with for replaced by lapply
f <- function(frame)
{
    if (!inherits(frame, "data.frame") || is.null(attr(frame, 
        "terms"))) 
        return(as.matrix(frame))
    frame[] <- lapply(frame, function(x) {
        if (is.character(x))
            as.numeric(factor(x))
        else if(!is.numeric(x))
            as.numeric(x)
        else x
    })
    X <- model.matrix(attr(frame, "terms"), frame)[, -1L, drop = FALSE]
    colnames(X) <- sub("^`(.*)`", "\\1", colnames(X))
    class(X) <- c("rpart.matrix", class(X))
    X
}
```

However, how do I get the entire rpart package to speed up?

Is it possible to download the rpart code and make these changes?

Also, I understand that the reason for the slow down is the piece of code which converts the categorical variable to 0/1 kind of 'flattened out variable'. Is this really necessary? Isn't it possible to treat a categorical variable differently in the internal implementation by just maintaining a list for each factor maybe, to mark the rows which use this factor?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: did you figure it out? would you be nice if there was a github repo that had the full code? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use trace to change the function codes in rpart.matrix

```
trace("rpart.matrix", where=asNamespace("rpart"), edit=TRUE)
```