Average run time for making a decision tree in R?
Current code:
dt_model <- rpart(quality ~ ., method = "class", data = train_data)

I am wondering what the average time is to run a decision tree model in R? I have a dataset of 12 columns and 1600 rows, I am trying to build a classification model to predict quality based on all other chemical parameters (the other 11 columns). Attached is a image of the code. Am i doing this right? Its taken hours and still nothing. The train-data is a subset of 70% of my data. Any advice would be appreciated.
I have tried re running the code and simplifying the model. I'm not sure what else to do. The data I am using can be found here.


Hi Savannah Jobkar, welcome to SO.  Please do not add code as an image for these reasons. Instead, remove the image and add the code in a codeblock e.g three backticks "````" (without the quotes), then add code on a new line, then three backticks on a new line after the code. Also, as your question is not strictly about programming or debugging code, it is likely it may be closed as off-topic for this site. However, hopefully someone with experience using your method may be able to comment.

It may also be useful to include information regarding the specifications of the computer that you are running your analysis on.

Likely there is an issue with your computer RAM. Try running the same code in the cloud using either POSIT cloud or Google COLAB and see if there is a difference.

Perhaps relevant? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/slow-convergence-with-rpart.  This notes that unordered factors (esp with many levels) can create a big performance bottleneck for rpart. These questions also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443068/how-do-i-get-rpart-to-work-with-increased-number-of-factors and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19207/r-rpart-taking-too-much-time-on-data-set and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145373 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195021 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237486
